# VSTO Infopath Form Security Problem

Tags: vsto, infopath

I have a VS2008 project - an Office 2007 InfoPath form customization with a little code behind.  I've run the publish wizard to create an msi install.  It's just going to be used by fellow developers (deployment template) who have all the base components already installed (framework, VSTO runtime).

I've read all the security documentation I can find, but nothing seems particularly applicable to my situation.

When the code behind is executed on a machine where the install has run, this is the error:

```
System.Security.SecurityException
Request failed.
at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.MsxmlNavigator.IsValidNode(MsxmlNode test)
at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.MsxmlNavigator.MoveToFirstChild()
-- one of my calls
at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.MoveToChild(String localName, String namespaceURI)
-- more of my code follows
```

Since this is my code running, this tells my the security is unrelated to my custom .dll being loaded I would think.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but I fixed it by changing the security level on the InfoPath form.

Tools >> Form Options >> Security and Trust

I cleared the checkbox for "Automatically determine..." and set the form for full trust, and added a certificate.

Of course, for dev purposes the cert was self-signed, which I highly doubt will fly when I publish the form to a SharePoint site (something to be dealt with tomorrow... or today if I get that far...)